# How to change the dot of the letter "i" to another character?

Tags: fonts, symbols, positioning, letters

How to change the dot of the letter "i" to another character, so that works on Latex/MathJax.

For example:

$i^\star$, how to replace the dot by the star?

When I type ´ + i displays:

í

Is there a way to replace ´ by other character?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The macro `\i` prints an `i` without the dot when in text mode.  Then, just use `\overset` to set something above it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{*}{\text{\i}}$
or
$\overset{+}{\text{\i}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you know of a way for this on MathJax?

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. I am sorry, I don't use MathJax, and as I understand it, questions pertaining strictly to the use of MathJax are "off-topic" on this site.  However, if someone reads your comment and knows the answer, you may get a return comment.

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. This site, https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html, has a section about the use of AMSmath within MathJax

Comment: -oh ok, thanks.

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. $\overset{*}{\imath}$ seems to work in MathJax, although it gives an italic dotless i. You can use a unicode dotless i if you want it upright; $\overset{*}{ı}$ seems to work.

Comment: @NickMatteo Indeed,  works good. The former is another new alternative to the currently mentioned. You could post it as an answer. The later idea also works but it's a match with TonyK's answer.

Comment: @NickMatteo: Indeed! I didn't see your solution, hidden among the comments to an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Using `accents` package I can obtain another same output like `\overset`.  Here there is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}


\begin{document}
Here there is a first example:
$\accentset{\ast}{\text{\i}}$. After I add another examples $\accentset{\circ}{\text{\i}}$ or $\accentset{\diamond}{\text{\i}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Note that the symbols are slightly more little than `\overset` command.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 4):

Mathjax accepts this:

```
$\overset{*}{\text{ı}}$
```

That strange character is the Turkish dotless `i`. It's a bit of a hack, but it wörks:

[image]

Comment: ohh, indeed a bit of a  hack, thank you. Bwt welcome to participate on TeX $\ddot\smile$ (try this on MathJax)